# Putting $10$ distinct objects into $2$ identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I asked someone the number of ways to put $10$ distinct to $2$ identical boxes and the reply was : just take one object and put it into one box and compare. So, that's just $\frac{2^{10}}{2}$.

I didn't understand that "take one object" and "compare" portions.

Comment: What are you even counting? What is the question you asked?

Comment: "I asked this question" ... what question?

Comment: I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach the question is to pick some subset of the objects to put in one box.  There are $2^{10}$ ways to do this.  You then put the rest of the objects in the other box.  As the boxes are identical, you have counted each configuration twice, so divide by $2$.

Another approach is to pick one object and put it in a box.  That makes the boxes different.  Now pick some subset of the remaining items to put with the first one, which you can do in $2^{(10-1)}$ ways.  Put the rest in the other box and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, distinguish the boxes as box zero and box one. Now you are counting the number of ten digit binary strings ($2^{10}$) except that it doesnt matter which box is which (you can switch all the digits) so $\frac{2^{10}}{2}$

As far as what that person meant, consider asking the source to elaborate.